# Tidy way to summarize several columns of data in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have a large dataframe of transcript IDs and their associated gene names, as well as a column that indicates if a certain model reported that gene/transcript as significant. Every transcript will always be linked to a single gene, although each gene is associated with multiple transcripts. Here's a reproducible example:

```
transcript <- c('t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7','t8', 't9', 't10')
gene <- c('g1', 'g1', 'g1', 'g2', 'g2', 'g2', 'g3','g3', 'g3', 'g3')
model1 <- c('TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE')
model2 <-c('FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE')
shared <- data.frame(transcript, gene, model1, model2)
shared

transcript gene model1 model2
<chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
t1  g1  TRUE    FALSE   
t2  g1  TRUE    FALSE   
t3  g1  TRUE    FALSE   
t4  g2  FALSE   TRUE    
t5  g2  FALSE   TRUE    
t6  g2  FALSE   TRUE    
t7  g3  TRUE    TRUE    
t8  g3  TRUE    TRUE    
t9  g3  TRUE    TRUE    
t10 g3  TRUE    TRUE
```

I'd like to condense and summarize this df by the number and identity of TRUE values into something like this:

```
n_transcripts n_genes transcripts genes
<dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
model1  7   2   t1;t2;t3;t7;t8;t9;t10   g1;g3
model2  7   2   t4;t5;t6;t7;t8;t9;t10   g2;g3
```

I've tried creating a blank df and summarizing from the initial df, but keep getting held up when it comes to distinguishing between model1 and model2. In reality, I have dozens of models and would like to avoid going through each model manually. Does anyone have ideas about where to start with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot to longer format on model columns and filter only those rows that have value TRUE. Group by model and summarise wanted values.

```
shared %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = matches("^model[0-9]+$"),
    names_to = "model"
  ) %>%
  filter(value == TRUE) %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  summarise(
    n_transcripts = n(),
    n_genes = length(unique(gene)),
    transcripts = str_c(unique(transcript), collapse = ";"),
    genes = str_c(unique(gene), collapse = ";"),
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of doing this.

My approach is to use the package `dplyr` which excels at summarizing data like this. However, it works best when your data is in tidy form, meaning it is perfectly square and each column is a variable. This means that the two columns "model1" and "model2" have to become one, like this:

```
require(dplyr)

shared <- shared %>% 
  gather(., key = "model", value = "expr", -c(1:2))
```

This puts the model1 and model2 rows on top of each other, and their resulting TRUE/FALSE are put into their own variable, which I call `expr` here.

Your data does have more rows now, but it is much easier now to summarize, as we can use the `dplyr::group_by()` on the "model" column and sum the rest. First we have to fix some other things.

In your data your TRUE/FALSE values are "character" values, and not logical. This means that R understands these values like names and not like yes/no, 0/1 or what ever. As we are going to count these, i change them to values like this:

```
shared[shared == "TRUE"] <- 1
shared[shared == "FALSE"] <- 0

shared$expr <- as.numeric(shared$expr)
```

Forcing the `expr` type to `as.numeric()` as i do here was needed, as it had changed to "character" again. This might be a fluke on my part.

Anyways, we are now ready to summarize. If your are unfamiliar to `dplyr`, then the next part might seem confusing:

```
shared <- shared %>% 
  .[.$expr == 1, ] %>%  #Remove the rows with FALSE (0)
  group_by(model) %>% 
  summarize(n_transcripts = sum(expr), #Sum all the TRUE (1)
            n_genes = length(unique(gene)), #Count unique genes
            transcripts = paste(unique(transcript), collapse = ";"), 
            genes = paste(unique(gene), collapse = ";"))
```

A lot of things are happening here, and `dplyr` allows us to do all of them in one fell swoop. I'm using the `%>%` (pipe) operator to pass the result of each function to the next. The real meat of the this function/call is the function `summarize()` which will count/paste/tally the data for each unique value in the "model" column which in this case is "model1" and "model2"

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanations of each step!